# Save data on webserver without php or database

Tags: html, database, mobile, webserver

I´ve an old ftp which does not support php or any database. Just html. 
Is there any way to save data on it from a desktop or mobile application?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, for sure ftp...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your application (as long as it's not client-side JavaScript) can use FTP to manipulate files on the server.

Comment: Ok I understand that. But how can I manipulate them? Thought I would need php for that and that isn´t supported.

Comment: Your application can connect to your server via FTP, just as you connect to it using some FTP program. How exactly you'll go about doing that depends on the language your app is written in.